# R ggplot2 with reshape (melt function) selectively graph data sets

Tags: r, reshape, ggplot2

I am using ggplot to graph a number of data sets, however I would like to plot them so that each data set has its own `geom_line` function so that I can seperate the lines out and hide them if required.

```
 ggplot(MeanFrameMelt, aes(x=variable, y=value, 
           color=Legend, group=Legend)) + geom_line()
```

Input table after transformed with the melt function in the package reshape:

```
Legend        variable  value
table_A.txt V1  0.008927491
table_B.txt V1  0.009080929
table_C.txt V1  0.008513332
table_D.txt V1  0.008337751
table_A.txt V2  0.008957742
table_B.txt V2  0.009100265
table_C.txt V2  0.008508966
```

table A should be one `geom_line` (line on the graph) table B a second `geom_line` and so on. Is this possible or do I have to go back and change the melting of the previous data frame?

Edit:
ok this is the melt function:

```
library(plyr)
library(reshape)    
MeanFrameMelt <- melt(MeanFrame2, id.vars="Legend")
```

The data i've given you is of only two points for each line, so imagine you have hundreds of points from each table (A, B, C, and D) hence there will be four lines on this graph. I want to be able to switch off each line with a checkbox, but for this I need to have a unique identifier for each line which will allow me to do this. So what I was thinking is to do a seperate `+ geom_line(for table A) + geom_line(for table B) + geom_line(for table C)...`

I hope this clarifies thinks a bit.

Edit2: this is what the graph looks like now, and it should look like this after aswell, but with 4 `geom_line` calls instead of just one that it has now:

[image]

Comment: I'm tempted to vote to close on the basis that it not possible to tell what is being asked. Please include code that creates a representative "MeanFrameMelt" and say what sort of lines you want appearing .... where?

Comment: how can you vote to close a question, I thought that until the person who asked the question doesn't accept an answer the question stays open

Comment: @user1872432 checkbox on ggplot2? are u sure?

Comment: no the checkboxes are going to be added with `gwidget: gcheckboxgroup` which can render with checkboxes. I need to conditionally add layers by making a plot object, say p, and adding layers with + and the appropriate call.

Comment: There is no barrier to voting 'close' on any question. I was tempted to do so just to demonstrate your confusion on this point, but you have added information so it wouldn't  be appropriate. Unfortunately you have still not added data and the image you link to would have been more appropriately been added through the SO image mechanisms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is close to what you want:

```
ggplot(MeanFrameMelt, aes(x=variable, y=value, 
       color=Legend, group=Legend))+ geom_line(aes(linetype=Legend))
```

**Edit** After OP clarification

With ggplot2( Lattice also) you can  combine data sources and subsetting for each layer

Here for example I choose to show only 2 lines

```
library(ggplot2)
  ggplot(dat, aes(x=variable, y=value, ,
                          color=Legend, group=Legend))+ 
  geom_line(subset= .(Legend %in% c('table_A.txt','table_D.txt')))
```

[image]

You can bind your check box to the list of line to show.

```
 geom_line(subset= .(Legend %in% visibleCheckedList))
```

Comment: This just changes the line for each table to a different dashed line. Sorry I guess I wasn't being very clear. I've edited my original question.

Comment: @user1872432 yes. Can you for example add a picture to your question using MSPaint...

Comment: I posted a link to an image, hope it helps.

Comment: This way of subsetting apparently does not work any more with the latest ggplot2 version.